What does $v$ actually represent in pulley problems?

Let us consider the problem of two pulleys with boxes attached to their ends. One pulley is movable, and the other is not. The problem requires us to find a relationship between velocities of these two boxes. Picture:
First from the first, we can estabilish the equation for inextensible rope:
$$l = const$$
$$l = 2l_a + l_b + C$$
Where $a$ and $b$ denote left and right pulley respectively, and $C$ represents other constant length of the rope (i.e. length around pulley).
By taking the derivative with respect to time, we obtain:
$$0 = 2v_a + v_b$$
This means that: $v_b = -2v_a$ . However, in standard notation it's assumed that $v=| \vec{v}|$ . We know that the modulus of velocity cannot be negative. In this problem, do $v_b$ and $-2v_a$ actually represent j components of velocity vectors:
$$\vec{v_b} = v_b \hat{\textbf{j}}$$
$$\vec{v_a} = -2v_a \hat{\textbf{j}}$$

By your definition that $v=dl/dt$, $v$ is just the rate of change in the lengths of the rope segments supporting their respective masses. Here you define $v$ to be a scalar, since $l$ is also a scalar, and the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a scalar variable is another scalar function. When $v_a$ is positive, $l_a$ decreases, and vice versa. Meanwhile, $v_b=-2v_a$ simply means that the rate of change of the rope supporting mass $b$ is twice the rate of change of the rope supporting mass $a$, and the change is in the opposite "direction". By "direction" here we mean "increase" and "decrease"—if the length of rope segment $b$ increases, then the length of rope segment $a$ decreases, and vice versa.
You may also assign a (positional) sense of direction and speed to the quantities by noting that you may write $\vec{v}=|\vec{v}|\hat{j}$ where you can define $\hat{j}$ to be positive upwards and negative otherwise. In this case, you have
$$\vec{v}_b=|\vec{v}_b|\hat{j}=-2\vec{v}_a=2|\vec{v}_a|(-\hat{j})$$
which tells you that mass $b$ moves at twice the speed mass $a$ moves, in the opposite direction.

the bold of you answer is exactly the problem, but the end: one dimensional vectors? I mean mathwise I like it, but physics-wise...it offends the senbsibilities.

So it turns out that it’s not velocity but rate of change, and you have to put it in the absolute value to get speed, otherwise it’s just the rate of change? If I got it right.

@AlexanderDjurovich Not quite. A derivative can always be interpreted as a rate of change of something in the numerator with respect to something in the denominator. In this sense, the term velocity is the rate of change of position with respect to time. Take the absolute value, and you get the speed. Meanwhile, your quantity $dl/dt$ is the rate of change of rope length with respect to time, for which we do not usually give a specific term. In an easier-to-digest language, all of these quantities conveys "how fast" something changes when something else changes.
